# How do I use a custom bucket URL with aws-sdk

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Say I have an S3 bucket:

`media.coolstuff.com`

I have enabled static website hosting for the domain, and this is what AWS gives me as the URL:

`media.coolstuff.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

I've made a CNAME from my subdomain to the AWS domain. In my bucket I've put an `index.html` and made it public, and visiting `media.coolstuff.com` successfully renders it, so I know the redirect works as it should.

I am trying to figure out how to use the `aws-sdk` gem to return URLs using the subdomain for objects in the bucket.

Here's the code:

```
creds = Aws::Credentials.new(access_key, secret_access_key)
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
  credentials: creds,
  endpoint: 'http://media.coolstuff.com',
  region: 'us-east-1'
)
bucket = s3.bucket('media.coolstuff.com')
obj = bucket.object('index.html')

obj.public_url
=> "http://media.coolstuff.com.media.coolstuff.com/index.html"
```

As you can see, the public url has the bucket duplicated. I get why this is: the bucket name is prefixed to the endpoint. But here, it shouldn't be. I don't know how to get around this.

Similarly, trying to get the `etag` fails because it can't figure out the right URL:

```
obj.etag
Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError: unable to connect to `media.coolstuff.com.media.coolstuff.com`; SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#public_url-instance_method)you can do this with

```
object.public_url(virtual_host: true)
```

Don't change the endpoint from the default - this is used for the actual api calls to S3